# Is there a one-off method to replace print()/cut() to message()/warning() in r

Tags: r, github, package, cran

I want to replace print()/cat() by message()/warning() as I want it to be suppressed.

However, my code looks quite nested print()/cat() and used print()/cat() multiple times.

I wonder if there is an easier way to fix this problem one-off.

Instead of do packageStartupMessage() & suppressPackageStartupMessages() for each time I used cat() and print()

Also, I am not quite sure, should I just replace print()/cat() directly without affect setMethod() and other functions.

Also, I also get advice about, but how can I used that in my situation?

```
if(verbose)cat(..) (or maybe stop()) if you really have to write text to the console.
(except for print, summary, interactive functions)
```

this is my code.

```
setMethod("print", "ga", function(x, ...) str(x))

setMethod(
  "show", "ga",
  function(object) {
    cat("An object of class \"ga\"\n")
    cat("\nCall:\n", deparse(object@call), "\n\n", sep = "")
    cat("Available slots:\n")
    print(slotNames(object))
  }
)
... ...

if (x$type == "real-valued") {
    cat(paste("Search domain = \n"))
    print(x$domain, digits = digits)
  }
```

Comment: You still have 2 print statements, replace both with `cat`?

Comment: But cat() is also not a suppressed function. I have to replace both cat() and print()

Comment: It looks like you're using a `show` method to build the console representation of your class. Perhaps you should instead declare a `format` method which builds the representation as a character string. That way, you never have to explicitly call `cat` or `print`

Comment: Thank you for reply Allan. What is a ```format``` method?

Comment: You keep posting this incomplete code.  Where is that final `if` statement?  Is it really standing alone, outside of any function?  That doesn't make sense.  Regarding your question, you're allowed to use `print` and `cat` in `show` methods, but should not be using them in other functions/methods unless a user asks for verbose output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone's helping today. The solution I figure out is just replacing all the print() and cat() function to message().